# adjust elements in html during window resizing for website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So i'm Trying to convert a non responsive html page into a responsive one
and it's a pretty simple page with an image some text on top of it and an email submit field below it.
So whenever I shrink my page the email submit field just starts to go up the page. The text field resizes (like going from all words in 2 lines to 4-5 lines ). The submit field overlap on top of the text field due to it requiring more space now (going form 2 lines to 4-5 lines). How can I adjust that in CSS so that my submit field remains always below the text field

**Note** scroll down to see the result.

```css
#botText2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 107%;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    color: rgba(4,45,72,1);
}

.subfield {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 122%;
    padding-left: 38%;
    padding-right: 6%;

}
```

```html
<span class="bot-text" id="botText2">some 2-3 lines of text</span>
<form class="subfield" action="/signup"  method="post">
  <input type="text" id="emailInput" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email here">
  <input type="submit" id="inputSubmit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Comment: You can just use @media queries to add different styling for different screen sizes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: media queries will work only when display is below certain width or height however this is happening as soon as the window is resized . should I be aiming for that screen sizes only i.e for all elements to adjust when it reaches some resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

Add margin or padding to `.subfield`:

```
.subfield {
    padding-bottom: 20% /*for example*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't absolutely position your elements, or you will only be able to achieve responsiveness through media queries. Allow your document to flow naturally, only interrupting this flow when absolutely necessary.

This allows the browser to determine the sizing/positioning for best results. By using percentages as opposed to fixed values will allow for a bit more fluidity, but dependent on the parent.

You can see below by commenting out most of your positioning, the browser gives the desired results as default behavior. So my answer would simply be to understand that less can certainly be more in many cases.

```css
#botText2 {
  /* z-index: 5; */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* margin-top: 107%; */
  /* padding-left: 6%; */
  /* padding-right: 6%; */
  color: rgba(4, 45, 72, 1);
}

.subfield {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* z-index: 6; */
  /* float: left; */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* margin-top: 122%; */
  /* padding-left: 38%; */
  /* padding-right: 6%; */
}
```

```html
<span class="bot-text" id="botText2">some 2-3 lines of text</span>
<form class="subfield" action="/signup" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="emailInput" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email here">
  <input type="submit" id="inputSubmit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```